# Django, revover a model with multi foreign key

Tags: python, django

I would like to show all favorites of connected user.
Each user can add his own favorites. I created a model to manage this action. 
In this one, I have two foreign key. One for the user and the second for the "favorite".

models.py

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    drud = models.ForeignKey(Drud)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.drud.secure_key
```

On my view, I want to show all favorite **Drud** of connected user. I tried to do something like that:

views.py

```
favorite = Favorite.objects.filter(drud=[d.secure_key for d in Drud.objects.filter(user=request.user)])
```

But, that does work...

Comment: "That does work..." 1) Presumably you meant doesn't work. 2) Please say the error you're getting or what happens which is not the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
fav_druds = request.user.favorite_set.values_list('drud', flat=True)
```

In the template you can do:

```
{% for drud in fav_druds %}
    {{drud.id}}: {{drud.secure_key}}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit:

```
favs = request.user.favorite_set.all()

{% for fav in favs %}
    {{fav.drud.id}}: {{fav.drud.secure_key}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This will return list of `Drud` ids or `Drud` objects?

Comment: it works, but I recover all id and I don't know how to show in my templates if they are several Druds

Comment: are you sending it in the context from the view ?

Comment: Ok.. in the view, if you `print fav_druds` does it print anything on the console?

Comment: I posted the variable {{ fav_drud }} in the templates, I have "[1]" a list as result.

Comment: Wonderful !!!! Thank you very much for your help. I'm sorry but I haven't enough reputation to vote up...!